# Please Help in_app_purchase unable to purchase, says Item unavailable in your country

Tags: android, ios, flutter, in-app-purchase

So i did all the steps in the flutter_inapp_purchase: ^5.3.1 [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inapp_purchase) i publish a close test of my app and added testers. i see the Consumable IAP loading in my app. But the problem am having is that when i click on the buy button it say item unavailable in you country and can't make a purchase. so i am stuck at this point for weeks now somebody please help

[Please See ScreenShot Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhqcY.gif)

Answer (score 2):

This one caught me too (for a couple of days). For me I needed to complete the section (on the App Dashboard) "select countries and regions" for the Release version of the app (even though I was only publishing to internal testing).

The reason is that the internal testing track is synced with the Release track.

After that, it still didn't work until I "Published" the changes on the "Publishing Overview" page.  Which was quite nerve-racking because the app wasn't released and the wording makes it seem like the app will be published for users.  That luckily wasn't the case, the "Publish" action just saves your changes to the available countries

After that the IAP worked correctly.

I hope this helps.